# Proving convergence of sequence $a_n = \int^n_1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have a sequence $(a_n)$ defined by:

$$a_n = \int^n_1 \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx$$

I want to prove that this sequence converges, and I have been given a hint:

> Prove, for $m \geq n \geq 1$ that $|a_m - a_n| \leq n^{-1}$.

After that is proven, then the sequence is Cauchy and must converge.

My problem is that I cannot prove this. I've tried evaluating this integral:

$$ |a_m - a_n| = \left|\int^m_n  \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx\right|$$

And my hope was that eventually, after application of some known inequalities e.g. $\frac{1}{n} \cos n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and the triangle law, eventually I'd end up with the result, but I haven't been successful in getting all the terms with $m$ in them to cancel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\left|\int\limits_{n}^{m}{\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\text{ d}x}\right|\le\int\limits_{n}^{m}{\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right|\text{ d}x}\le\int\limits_{n}^{m}{\frac{1}{x^2}\text{ d}x}$.

Comment: If $m\geq n$ then $\frac{1}{m}\leq\frac{1}{n}$ therefore $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\leq \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Hmm, that's actually really obvious, I should get more sleep before posting questions, haha.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of the integral of $\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036907/convergence-of-the-integral-of-frac-cosxx2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left|\int^m_n  \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx\right|\le$ $\left|\int^m_n  |\frac{\cos x}{x^2}| dx\right|\lt \left|\int^m_n  \frac{1}{x^2} dx\right|=| \int^m_n d(-\frac{1}{x})|=[-\frac{1}{x}]_n^m=-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n} $

Hence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.